# Stereo chemistry of Hoffman elimination reaction?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

Does Hoffman elimination go through syn or anti elimination?

I referred Solomons and Fryhle,Paula bruice,L G Wade but none mentioned about the stereo chemistry of the reaction.

Does it vary as per the reaction conditions or is it unknown?

Comment: My guess is that it's an *anti* elimination, considering the fact that it's used to make *trans*-cyclooctene.

Comment: I wondered why all the authors I mentioned in the post mentioned about the stereo chemistry of cope elimination but not that of Hoffman elimination.